# How can i recursively call, query filter and change an api call using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I cant post full code as its closed source, but the code would look something like this:

```
var total = await apiCall(arg1, queryParams(arg1, argThatNeedsToChange)).Select(e =>
               e.Where(i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value && i => i.value2 == value2)
                .SelectMany(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Sum(i => (decimal) i.Amount))
                .Select(Convert.ToUInt64);
```

This works (when its not obfuscated), but the api call returns a set of different items, up to a max of 100. this code does not cover if there are over 100 items that match the .Where filters and will therefore have an incorrect total. what i need to do is something like:

```
var total = await apiCall(arg1, queryParams(arg1, argThatNeedsToChange)).Select(e =>
                 While(e.Count % 1 == 0){ e.Concat(await ApiCall(args1, queryParams(args1, e[e.Count - 1].Valuexyz)))} // this should return 'e' concatenated with the results of the looped api calls.
                .Where(i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value && i => i.value2 == value2)
                .SelectMany(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Sum(i => (decimal) i.Amount))
                .Select(Convert.ToUInt64);
```

a property of the last object in the result of the api call, is used in subsequent api calls in order to page back through results further than 100. i need to add this to the linq to get all items that satisfy the filters, not just the top most 100.

i should also note that the api call returns an `IObservable` using `RxNet`, so in this case im awaiting an `IObservable`, not an `async Task` function. The async function is converted to `IObservable` internally using `Observable.FromAsync()`

Comment: I usually create a helper method in c# that performs the recursion.  Then call the helper method from a linq.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just not chain stuff like this, and instead have

```
var allResults = new List<MyType>();
string pagingToken = null; // or whatever type this is
do{
   var result = await apiCall(arg1, queryParams(arg1, argThatNeedsToChange);
   allResults.AddRange(result); // or result.Items or whatever
   pagignToken = result.XXX; // (whatever has the paging token)
}while(pagingToken != null);
```

and here

```
var total = allResults
.Where(i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Where(i => i => i.value == value && i => i.value2 == value2)
                .SelectMany(i => i => i.value == value)
                .Sum(i => (decimal) i.Amount))
                .Select(Convert.ToUInt64);
```